# Is there an app that allows me to monitor time spent using an application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, logs, monitoring

Is there a tool that allows you to monitor the amount of time spent actively interacting with an application? This would be useful for development work to get an idea of just how long projects take.

EDIT:

I've been using RescueTime as it tracks apps, catagorises them based on productivity levels, and also looks at web pages visited.

Comment: You have two good questions here. Generally, it works best if each question gets a separate post, rather than combining more-or-less unrelated questions.

Comment: Yes, @Daniel is right. I've removed the first question since people have already answered the second one. Please feel free to ask your first question again separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application [Time Sink](http://www.macworld.com/article/160398/2011/06/timesink1.html) ($5, Many Tricks) tracks the amount of time you spend in each application (and each window within an application).

Answer (score 4):

[Timing](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/timing-time-tracking-for-humans/id431511738?mt=12) helps in tracking time spent in applications (and their windows) as well. It's similar to Time Sink but seems to provide more grouping and reporting options.

Answer (score 2):

[TimeEdition](http://www.timeedition.com/) is an application that I just found. I haven't used it yet, but it's free. However, it doesn't have as many features as Time Sink.

Answer (score 2):

macOS Catalina might bring Screen Time as in iOS to Mac too.

> **Usage reports** Screen Time creates usage reports that show you how much
> time is being spent on your Mac, which apps are used most and how many
> notifications are received. With iCloud, Screen Time combines all your
> usage information and syncs Downtime settings and App Limits across
> iPhone, iPad and Mac.
>
> **Downtime With Screen Time**: you can schedule
> downtime so you (or your child) can only use specific apps you’ve
> approved.
>
> **App Limits With App Limits** you can set the amount of time
> you want to use your apps and websites. Set App Limits for total time,
> categories or specific apps.
>
> **Combined Limits** Create combined limits
> with a combination of app categories, specific apps or websites.
>
> **One More Minute** When a limit is met, you can tap “one more minute” to give
> you time to quickly save your work or wrap up a conversation.

emphasis and some punctuation mine.

https://www.apple.com/in/macos/catalina/features/

Answer (score 0):

[*Time Sink*](http://manytricks.com/timesink/) seems to do this job — a job that I find useless —, and costs only 5 little dollars.

[*Tictoc*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tictoc/id412307572?mt=12) keeps track of time spent in tasks, rather than in applications. Which starts to be a little more useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Apps Usage](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apps-usage/id1068673201?mt=12) is an app for Mac users, who want to know, how much time they spent on each used application.