# Mac OS X app for measuring time spent in apps

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an app that allows me to monitor time spent using an application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28769/is-there-an-app-that-allows-me-to-monitor-time-spent-using-an-application)

Is there app which will tell me that for example, today I spent 30 minutes in Safari, 1 hour in XCode, etc...
Thanks

Comment: A google search for `time tracker mac` gave me this: [http://www.rescuetime.com](http://www.rescuetime.com) Didn't use it, but according to it's page it does what you want.

Comment: [*Time Sink*](http://manytricks.com/timesink/) seems to do this job — a job that I find useless —, and costs only 5 little dollars.

Comment: [*Tictoc*](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tictoc/id412307572?mt=12) keeps track of time spent in tasks, rather than in applications. Which starts to be a little more useful.

Comment: [Apps Usage](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apps-usage/id1068673201?mt=12) is an app for Mac users, who want to know, how much time they spent on each used application. It can be a good solution for you.

Comment: A free option in Mac App Store is [CurrentKey Stats](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/currentkey-stats/id1456226992?mt=12), in addition to app tracking, it also keeps track of how you spend time across Spaces

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Timesink](http://manytricks.com/timesink/) by ManyTricks. I've used it for years and it's perfect for tracking where you spend your time on your mac.